# pytesseract - Recognize text on different backgrounds

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to recognize the page number from a colored image but pytesseract does not recognize nothing with the command:

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test\\colorimage.jpg")))
```

Then i tried to binarize the same image: same result.
Finally I decided to adjust the binarized image by creating a "unique" background.
**Check this results map:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMD3M.jpg

How can I recognize text without edit the default image with Python?